# Компилятор выдаёт ошибку expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Tags: c++

Вчера написал программу, всё было хорошо, работала нормально. Сегодня решил кое-что в ней доделать, как выяснилось, что теперь там появилась ошибка, хотя код не редактировался с момента последнего "удачного" запуска.

Теперь выдаёт такую ошибку:

> [Error] expected unqualified-id before '{' token (скобка после объявления мэйна).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class publication
   {
       protected: char name[30];
                  float price;

       public :
           void getdata()
           {
               cout<<"Nazvanie knigi:"<<endl;
               cin>>name;
               cout<<"Tcena:"<<endl;
               cin>>price;
           }
           void putdata()
           {
               cout<<"Nazvanie knigi:"<<name<<endl;
               cout<<"Tcena:"<<price<<endl;
           }
            virtual void getData()=0;
            virtual void putData()=0;
            virtual bool isOversize()=0;
            virtual void getdat1()=0;
            virtual void putdat1()=0;
   };

class sales
{
    protected:
        float x[3];
    public:
        void getdat()
        {
            cout<<"Skidki (3 mesyatca):"<<endl;
            for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                cout<<i+1<<" mesyatc="; cin>>x[i];
            }
        }
        void putdat()
        {
            cout<<"Skidki (3 mesyatca):"<<endl;
            for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                cout<<i+1<<" mesyatc="<<x[i]<<endl;
            }
        }
        virtual void getdat1()=0;
        virtual void putdat1()=0;
};

  class book: public publication,public sales
          {
          private:
            int st;
          public:
            void getdat1()
            {
                sales::getdat();
            }

            void putdat1()
            {
                sales::putdat();
            }
            void getData()
            {
                publication::getdata();
                cout<<"Kol-vo stranic:"<<endl;
                cin>>st;
            }
            void putData()
            {
                publication::putdata();
                cout<<"Kol-vo stranic:"<<st<<endl;
            }
            bool isOversize()
            {
                return(st>800)? true:false;
            }

          };


    class tape: public publication,public sales
          {
          private:
            int m;
          public:
            void getdat1()
            {
                sales::getdat();
            }
            void putdat1()
            {
                sales::putdat();
            }
            void getData()
            {
                publication::getdata();
                cout<<"Kol-vo minut:"<<endl;
                cin>>m;
            }
            void putData()
            {
                publication::putdata();
                cout<<"Kol-vo minut:"<<m<<endl;
            }
            bool isOversize()
            {
                return(m>90)? true:false;
            }

          };


    class disk: public publication,public sales
        {
            private:
                char c;
                int r;
            public:
                void getdat1()
                {
                    sales::getdat();
                }

                void putdat1()
                {
                    sales::putdat();
                }
                void getData()
                {
                    publication::getdata();
                    cout<<"Tip zapisi[CD/DVD]?"<<endl;
                    cin>>c;
                    cout<<"Razmer?"<<endl;
                    cin>>r;
                }
                void putData()
                {
                    publication::putdata();
                    cout<<"Tip zapisi:";
                    if (c=='c') cout<<"CD"<<endl;
                    else cout<<"DVD"<<endl;
                    cout<<"Razmer:"<<r<<endl; 
                }
                bool isOversize()
                {
                    if (c=='c') return(r>700)? true:false;
                    else return(r>2800)? true:false;
                }
        };

//============================================================\\
int main()
{
    publication *pubarr[20];
    int n=0;
    char ch;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Book[B], Tape[T], Disk[D]?"<<endl;
        cin>>ch;
        if (ch=='b') pubarr[n]=new book;
        else if (ch=='t') pubarr[n]=new tape;
        else pubarr[n]=new disk;
        pubarr[n]->getData();
        pubarr[n]->getdat1();
        n++;
        cout<<"Continue[Y/N]?"<<endl;
        cin>>ch;
    }while(ch=='y');
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        pubarr[i]->putdata();
        pubarr[i]->putdat1();
        if(pubarr[i]->isOversize())
            cout<<"Prevyshenie razmera!"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: предлагаете угадать что за ошибка появилась? :)

Comment: я уже написал, что за ошибка появилась. Мне интересна причина её появления и возможность эту ошибку исправить, ибо понять в чём дело я не могу

Comment: смешно на самом деле :-) `=\\ ` вот тут вы экранировали перенос строки и получилось что строка с `main` продолжение комментария :)

Comment: каким редактором вы пользуетесь?

Comment: И это еще не самая жуть :)
Представьте, что вы торопитесь и, набирая комментарий `// What the f...ing???` слишком рано убираете руку с клавиши Shift, получая `// What the f...ing??/` и не замечая этого. А если и замечая - то что тут такого, казалось бы? А теперь представьте, что ваш компилятор поддерживает [триграфы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%A1%D0%B8)), о которых вы за ненадобностью вообще не вспоминаете. Саттер в какой-то из своих книг писал, что это не придуманный пример, а происшедший в реальности...

Comment: спасибо, даже не знал о такой функции). Пользуюсь Dev-C++, проблема решена)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Уберите в конце этой строки

```
//============================================================\\
```

две обратные наклонные черты, чтобы было вот так

```
//============================================================
```

И все у Вас получится :)

Причина кроется в том, что символ обратной косой черты (`\`) — это символ продолжения строки, если он стоит в конце строки. Все строки, заканчивающиеся обратной косой чертой (`\`), за которыми сразу следует символ новой строки, объединяются со следующей строкой в исходном файле, формируя логические строки из физических строк. [(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6aw8xdf2(v=vs.120).aspx#mt56)

Comment: стоит добавить объяснение что было не так :)

Comment: @Grundy Добавил :)

Comment: символ продолжения строки?

Comment: Забавно, что если после бэкслэша добавить пробел, проблема сохраняется.

Comment: [Быстрое воспроизведение проблемы](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22PTC8oHQgoBLA7ALgAgLYEMEAoBuB7WAEwEpoBvaZZAJwFNEBXa%2BZABgG5oBfIA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22clang380%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-Wall%22%7D%5D%7D).

Comment: @D-side, возможно даже не только пробел, но и любой пробельный символ, кроме собственно переноса

Comment: Ага, в гцц даже много пробелов после `\\` все равно комментарят следующую  строку.

Comment: @avp Боюсь, что в MS не знают о существовании GCC :)

Comment: А при чем тут MS?

Comment: @avp При том, что в ответе цитата из MSDN. И Вы приводите комментарии относительно именно этой цитаты (является ли обратный слэш окончанием строки). Или нет?

Comment: Конечно, нет. Люди пользуются разными компиляторами и я просто добавил информацию о поведении gcc. Если те, кто пользуются clang, icc, ... напишут о них, просто станет больше информации. Разве не так?

Comment: @avp Ну если с позновательной точки зрения, тогда конечно же так.